# Android: How to get Drawable Image name

Tags: android, path, imageview, drawable

I want to get the name of the drawable image and want to store that name in a string. For example , for an Image, I might use a .png file named play.png or stop.png. I just want to know which image in drawable is used for the ImageView.. Is there any way to get the name of the drawable/(??.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I donot think there is any direct way to get name of drawable image unless you stores the image name along with image.

In XML you can do the following to set image name as an additional data to imageview

```
android:tag="btful.png"
```

Programmetically setting imagename

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewByID(R.id.img)// my image
img.settag("btful.png"); // to set an image name
```

you can get the image name by using getTag()

```
String imageName = (String)img.getTag();
```

Comment: is there any way to get drawableimageId that we can see in the R.java file?? Because I have already set some different tags for images.

Comment: without the setTag() can i get the png image name.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your second question "drawableImgId"why not use:

img.getId();

I have multiple images and need to know which img id I am passing to other activities, it works for me