# How get name or id Image in android

Tags: android

I would like to know how I can get name image. I use setImageResource(R.drawable.id). How I can get this sentence: "R.drawable.id" in code?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6611203/940096)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean the name of the image you are referring to, use this.

```
String resName = getResourceNameFromClassByID(R.drawable.class, R.drawable.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

`R` refers  to the `R.java` file under `gen` folder ..
[image]
every time you add a resource an id is created automatically in this file, so R should be resolved to your package name.R