# how to get image name from drawable on an existing imageview

Tags: java, android, imageview, filenames, imagebutton

like the title said, i really want to get a drawable name from my current image view

```
Imageview img = findViewById(R.id.IMG);
```

and it set with image from drawable named "img001.png"
and I have a button that will change the image to "img002.png", and when clicked again it should be changed the image again to "img001". 
i use code like this

```
if (myimg == "img001"){
myimg= "img002"
}else if (myimg == "img002"){
myimg= "img001"}
```

it not work since "myimg" is null at start, so i want "myimg" to check which image is already in use.

i ve googled some info how to get resource name but all I got is how to get resource id from its name.

Comment: Well, if `myimg` can be null you could check for that and set `"img001"` in that case. Additionally you should compare strings using `.equals()` and not via `==`.

Answer (score 0):

Get the image name like is explained here:
[Android: How to get Drawable Image name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611203/android-how-to-get-drawable-image-name)

Then compare the name by using equals():

```
if("img001".equals(imageName)) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using custom tags instead of finding resource name, changing tag for that imageview and checking that in if-else condition instead of taking image names. When you apply resource to image view, assign that resource id as tag to image view.

```
if(imgView != null) {
    imgView.setImageResource(resourceId_1);
    imgView.setTag(resourceId_1);

    imgView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(imgView.getTag != null) {
                if(imgView.getTag() = resourceId_1) {
                    imgView.setImageResource(resourceId_2);
                    imgView.setTag(resourceId_2);
                } else if(imgView.getTag() = resourceId_2) {
                    imgView.setImageResource(resourceId_1);
                    imgView.setTag(resourceId_1);
                }
            } else {
                Log.v(TAG, "ImageView tag is null");
            }
        }
    }
}
```